# pasar variable a otra funcion

Tags: laravel-livewire

quiero saber si se puede pasar variables a otras funciones de livewire

Actualmente estoy escuchando el numero id de una habitación

```
public $habitacion;
protected $listeners = ['readHabitacion' => 'readHabitacion'];

public function readHabitacion($id)
{
   $this->habitacion = $id; // numero de habitación  a pasar //

}
```

Debo pasar el id a esta funcion:

```
public function addToCart($id)
    {


        

        $product = Product::find($id);


        \Cart::add([
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->nombre,
            'price' => $product->precio,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'attributes' => array(
                'image' => $product->imagen,
                 'habitacion' => $this->habitacion,  // Variable con el id //
            )
        ]);




    }
```

Hice un **dd($this->habitacion)**  pero me sale NULL

¿Como puedo pasar la variable $habitacion a la funcion addToCart??

Comment: Las funciones se encuentran en el mismo componente?

Comment: @JulioGuerrero si amigo